# How to make IntelliJ 2019.3+ not interpret XPath selectors as CSS selectors?

Tags: css, intellij-idea, xpath, jestjs

How to make IntelliJ 2019.3+ not interpret XPath selectors as CSS selectors?

In my case, I'm using Jest (a JavaScript Webdriver testing framework) and the $-notation shorthand which I suspect IntelliJ is interpreting as jQuery (which otherwise does require a valid CSS selection). See the screenshot below.

[image]

The testing code functions as intended, but these warnings are troublesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly - IDEA treats `$`  as `jQuery` and thus "*jQuery-CSS*" language is auto-injected in `$()` calls.
Deselecting the **js: JQuery selectors** language injection in ***Settings | Editor | Language Injections*** should fix the issue:

[image]

Comment: That was it. Nice :)